# Bind an control property to a property of a Class of the Window ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to Bind the Text Property of a TextBox to a Child of a of a Property of a ViewModel.

Here is my code:

---

foo.cs:

```
    public class foo()
    {
      public foo()
      {
        Bar = "Hello World";
      }

      public string Bar { Get; private Set;}
      //Some functions
    }
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public foo Property { Get; Set; }

      //some more properties

      public ViewModel()
      {

      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));            
      }
    }
```

Window.xaml.cs:

```
    public ViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }

    public Window()
    {
      MyViewModel = new ViewModel();
      this.DataContext = MyViewModel;
      MyViewModel.Property = new foo();
    }
```

Window.xaml:

```
    <!--
    Some controls
    -->

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Property.Bar}"></TextBox>
```

I also tried
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317229/wpf-binding-a-label-to-a-class-property)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918977/binding-to-a-viewmodels-child-class-properties), but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `ViewModel` but you never call it when `Property` is changed

try:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private foo _property;
  public foo Property
  { 
     get{ return _property; }
     set{ _property = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
  }

  .................
```